# How to autogenerate empid with string?

Tags: vb.net

i am using vb.net2005 and ms sql server2005 i want source code for autogenerate the empid in my table  . for example' sb1001'

Comment: what is the prefix "sb" related to? Is it fixed always as "sb" ? Will it be different based on some business logic?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer to your question is:

```
      For x As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        dt.Rows(x)("emp_id") = "sb" & x
      Next
```

dt represents your datatable